# SQL Server Error (Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.)

Tags: sql-server

We use Knowledge Sync for one of our applications and this has always worked in the past, but now I am getting this error.  We have recently updated our Knowledge Sync to version 10.  When I run this query in KS it previews fine, but never actually runs for an event.  So I tested the query in SQL Managment Studio and get this error. Any ideas?

```
 Select
AR_Customer.Customer_Number As 'Customer_Number',
AR_Customer_Site.Business_Name As 'Site_Name',
AR_Customer_Site.Site_Number As 'Site_Number',
AR_Customer_Site.GE1_Description As 'Site_City',
SY_System.System_Code As 'System_Type',
rmr.Item_Code As 'Item_Code',
System_Rmr.Bill_Cycle As 'Bill_Cycle',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Monthly_Amount) FROM AR_Customer_Recurring cr WHERE cr.Customer_System_Id = AR_Customer_System.Customer_System_Id AND (Cycle_Start_Date <= '{%Current Date MM/DD/YYYY%}') AND (Cycle_End_Date > '{%Current Date MM/DD/YYYY%}' )),0) As 'System_RMR',
SS_Inspection_Cycle.Inspection_Cycle_Code As 'Inspection_Cycle',
svt.Ticket_Number As 'Ticket_Number',
emd.Employee_Code As 'Dispatch_Tech',
svd.Dispatch_Time As 'Dispatch_Dispatch_Time',
svd.Arrival_Time As 'Dispatch_Arrival_Time',
svd.Departure_Time As 'Dispatch_Departure_Time',
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,svd.Arrival_Time,svd.Departure_Time)/60.000) As 'On_Site_Time',
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,svd.Dispatch_Time,svd.Arrival_Time)/60.0000) As 'Travel_Time',
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,svd.Dispatch_Time,svd.Departure_Time)/60.0000) As 'Total_Time'





From 
AR_Customer
Inner JOIN AR_Customer_Site On AR_Customer.Customer_Id = AR_Customer_Site.Customer_Id
Left Outer JOIN AR_Customer_System On AR_Customer_Site.Customer_Site_Id = AR_Customer_System.Customer_Site_Id
Inner JOIN SY_System On AR_Customer_System.System_Id = SY_System.System_Id
Left Outer JOIN AR_Customer_Recurring System_Rmr On AR_Customer_System.Customer_System_Id = System_Rmr.Customer_System_Id
Left Outer JOIN AR_Item rmr On System_Rmr.Item_Id = rmr.Item_Id
Left Outer JOIN SV_Inspection On AR_Customer_System.Customer_System_Id = SV_Inspection.Customer_System_Id
Left Outer JOIN SS_Inspection_Cycle On SV_Inspection.Inspection_Cycle_Id = SS_Inspection_Cycle.Inspection_Cycle_Id
Left Outer Join SV_Service_Ticket svt On AR_Customer_System.Customer_System_Id = svt.Customer_System_Id
Left Outer Join SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch svd On svt.Service_Ticket_Id = svd.Service_Ticket_Id
Left Outer Join SV_Service_Tech svdt On svd.Service_Tech_Id = svdt.Service_Tech_Id Left Outer Join SY_Employee emd On svdt.Employee_Id = emd.Employee_id

Where
AR_Customer.Customer_Id <> 1 And
(SY_System.System_Code Like '%Inspect%' And
case
    when (System_Rmr.cycle_start_date <= '{%Current Date MM/DD/YYYY%}'  and (System_Rmr.cycle_end_date <= {'1900-01-01'} or System_Rmr.cycle_end_date > '{%Current Date MM/DD/YYYY%}')) then 'Y'
    Else 'N'
end= 'Y' And

rmr.Item_Code Like '%Fire Alarm Inspection%' And
rmr.Item_Code <> 'Fire Insp Compliance-Rec' And
svt.Resolved_Date Between '{%Last Month Start Date MM/DD/YYYY%}' and '{%Last Month End Date MM/DD/YYYY%}' And
DateDiff(mi,svd.Arrival_Time,svd.Departure_Time) Is Not Null  And
SS_Inspection_Cycle.Inspection_Cycle_Code = 'Annual')
Order By
AR_Customer_Site.GE1_Description ASC
```

Comment: What is `'{%Last Month Start Date MM/DD/YYYY%}'`, how is it replaced / tokenized, and why on earth would you ever use a regional, ambiguous format like that, since it will be sensitive to language / dateformat / regional settings?

Comment: If any of your date columns have a time component then `BETWEEN the 1st of the month (at midnight) and the last of the month (at midnight)` is not going to get you accurate results. For consistency you should never use `BETWEEN` for date range queries regardless of the data type; much more reliable to use `>= 1st of month AND < 1st of *next* month`.

Comment: Finally, `'{%Current Date MM/DD/YYYY%}'` should be `CONVERT(date, GETDATE())` so you don't have to use string delimiters and bad tokenized date strings. Similarly, the beginning of last month is `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()), MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()), 1);` - so really your query should say `WHERE Resolved_Date >= {that} AND Resolved_Date < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);` ... all of these can be in the query so your application doesn't have to process them at all, and so your query works the same no matter where you run it.

Comment: Lots more on dates here: [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Comment: (Also, not related to your problem, but carriage returns and indentation go a long way toward readability / maintainability.)

Comment: @Aaron  I did not create this query.  It was much before my time here.  I hear you on the returns and indentation, but that is irrelevant to my issue here.  I have to figure out why this worked for years up until this week.